# Problem publishing images in Silverlight PivotViewer

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I'm working on a Silverlight PivotViewer app and using the Excel Pivot Collection tool to generate my image files.  Everything works perfectly except some images are not being published by the tool.  As a result, when the app launches, everything looks great except there are blank spaces where the unpublished images are supposed to be.  All of their data/facets are available if I click on a "blank" image.

When I dig a little deeper and look at the files that are generated, the missing images are not there. What's more interesting, if I look a the cxml file.  The images information is all there only the missing images are missing their "img" attribute.  For some reason, the Pivot Collection tool recognizes that there are images but chooses not to publish them.  I've tried re-creating the images as both PNGs and JPGs to no success.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the entire collection_files folder and the cxml file.  Republish the images and then add the newly published collection_files folder and cxml file to your project.